# How to save image from remote URL using C# asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, url, c#-3.0, webrequest

I am working on asp.net C# website in that I getting problem when I try to save image from remote URL.

I have tried with below c# code ...

// **C# code**

```
string remoteImageUrl= "http://www.bitpixels.com/getthumbnail?code=83306&url=http://live.indiatimes.com/default.cms?timesnow=1&size=200";
string strRealname = Path.GetFileName(remoteImageUrl);
string exts=Path.GetExtension(remoteImageUrl);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImageUrl,Server.MapPath("~/upload/")+strRealname + exts);
```

When I fetch image from above **remoteImageUrl** then 
 I getting error "**An exception occurred during a WebClient request.**"

How can I fetch and save remote url image and store it my website upload directory.

 or any other way to get remote url image.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  Are you getting any further information in the Exception? Any InnerException?

Comment: @David I get above exception when I download from remote url.

Comment: I get actual problem and solved it how it getting problem.. I was added extension into file using Path.GetExtension then it was breaked.

Comment: what is namespace for `Server.MapPath` ?

Comment: it says the name `Server` does not exists in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that problem The exception comes due to the extension..

When I getting extension of the remoteImageUrl Path.

```
string exts = Path.GetExtension(remoteImageUrl);
string strRealname = Path.GetFileName(remoteImageUrl);
```

It returns ".cms" so exception throws at that point,
I avoid the ".cms" extension from the remoteImageURL and then call

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImageUrl,Server.MapPath("~/upload/")+strRealname + exts);
```

It works fine.

Comment: So how do you "I avoid the ".cms" extension from the remoteImageURL" ??

Answer (score 1):

Yout code is just fine. Make sure your application pool identity, has access to "upload" folder with write access.

And if you are using a proxy server you should also specify this in web.config file.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yener, actually I solved it my self.. there was issue in extension.. when i was saved file with extension... Thanks Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Are you running under anything less than full trust? If so, you can't make arbitrary web requests either.